# How to make an alist without repeating key/values?

Tags: alists

When writing an alist where all the key/value pairs have keys that are variables, is there a convenient way to write this in Elisp without repetition?

eg:

```lisp
`((foo . ,foo)
  (long-variable-name . ,long-variable-name)
  (yet-another-long-variable-name . ,yet-another-long-variable-name)
  (you-get-the-idea . ,you-get-the-idea))
```

So the same structure could be written as:

```el
(alist-from-vars
  foo
  long-variable-name
  yet-another-long-variable-name
  you-get-the-idea)
```

... with an arbitrary number of arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to quote the variable, you need to use a macro instead of a function, e.g.,

```
(defmacro alist-from-vars (&rest vars)
  `(list ,@(mapcar (lambda (var) `(cons ',var ,var))
                   vars)))

(macroexpand '(alist-from-vars a b))
;; => (list (cons (quote a) a) (cons (quote b) b))

(let ((a 1)
      (b 2))
  (alist-from-vars a b))
;; => ((a . 1) (b . 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't get exactly what you're trying to get, but maybe this at least helps you find the way:

```lisp
(defun alist-from-vars (&rest vars)
  (mapcar (lambda (x) `(,x . ,(symbol-value x))) vars))

(let ((a 12)
      (b 24)
      (c 7))
  (alist-from-vars 'a 'b 'c))
```

Comment: You can just write `(cons x (symbol-value x))` in your lambda . More readable.